# Испозьзование UnitOfWork в трехуровневой архитектуре ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, архитектура

В DAL имеется ряд репозиториев. Все репозитории можно разбить на логические группы, определяющие некоторое поведение. Следует ли создавать единственный UnitOfWork-класс для всех репозиториев, или лучше создать несколько(IdentityUnitOfWork и т.п.)?

Comment: Александр, не могли бы вы подробнее описать проблему:
1. что рождает необходимость создавать подклассы UoW, чем жертвуете, отказавшись от подклассов?
2. можете ли предоставить фрагменты кода, например, интерфейсы UoW и одного из репозиториев, краткий пример сценария использования.

Comment: @kimaman2, использую как раз 2 вариант, но не доходило облепить интерфейсами, чтобы получать только нужные куски. Это как раз то, что мне нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: Если не сложно пометьте как ответ :) переклал из комента в ответы....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможны 2 решения, на мой взгляд: или вы создаете репозитории методом uow.CreateReposoty и тогда у вас большой монолит, либо все тот же монолит, но с кучей свойств вида IItem1Repository It1Repository { get; }, при втором подходе UoW можно облепить интерфейсами и в каждый сервис притащить только необходимый кусок (п.с. у меня в prod используется 1 вариант, но предпочел бы 2, жаль не от меня зависит)